# How to design an admin panel that can contain multiple questions with multiple games related?

Tags: website-design

I'm designing a backoffice panel of a website that administrate questions and games.

The main objective is that an admin can create games that can contain one or more questions. The problem is that one question can be related with multiple games.

The requeriments are:

1. There are multiple games
2. One game can contain multiple questions, and a question can be contained in more than one game at the same time (N-M relation)
3. In every game the questions can be ordered

Based on this requirements, I've designed this GUI, but I'm not sure if it's usable enough or there is a UX pattern for this case.

My proposal:

1- When creating/editing a question, there will be a checkbox for every game created, and user can check in what games the questions will be available.

[image]

2- When editing a game, there will be an sortable list with all the questions that have been checked for this game.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, when creating a new game, I have to navigate to each of the questions, edit them and assign them to the game? I would have thought it would be easier to select from a list of questions when creating the game.

Comment: Yes. I realize that the workflow is a little weird, but I didn't know how to improve. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should provide two sections to deal with questions and games.

Questions section should offer features:

- questions list (it should be categorized, if you consider categorization)
- add a question (with a possibility to define all the details regarding the question - like categorization etc.)
- edit a question
- delete a question

Games section should contain:

- games list
- add a game (again: with a possibility to define all the features of the game)
- edit a geme
- delete a game

While creating a game user should be able to:

- assign questions to a game - you can use a list of all questions with checkboxes or some container to drag from it and drop it in the "selected questions" area
- if there is no question, user should be able to add this new question; it should be also added to the main list of questions for further use in other games.

The list of questions (both in the Questions section and during game creation) consider that the list of questions can be long, and the questions can be long as well (so the list needs to be quite wide). I would suggest something like:

[image]

Edit: You could also provide a filter input to filter the available questions as you type. It would be handy if there are many questions to choose from.